# Generating strong UHF magnetic fields on a PCB

Tags: rf, pcb-antenna

I would like to generate a strong magnetic rf field in the order of 1 mT using a PCB structure in a frequency range from 200 MHz to 1 GHz over a region of 5 mm diameter. What could I do to produce such a magnetic field on a PCB?

What I have done in the past for lower frequencies (< 50 MHz): Using an RF amplifier that delivers ~20 watts and that tolerates 100% mismatch, I used a single loop or a planar spiral coil to short the amplifier output. This results in a current anti-node at the location of the loop and therefore an increased magnetic field strength.

Comment: Terminated ferrite core transformer with an airgap.

Comment: @mkeith Curious what ferrite you would suggest for this frequency range?

Comment: It was more of a suggestion or shot in the dark. I should have put a question mark at the end of it. Obviously it would have to be an RF material. But I am not sure whether the desired field can be reached that way.

Comment: What flux density did you achieve and at what frequency was this at when you experimented in the past using an RF amplifier. RMS voltage, spiral inductance and flux density values needed please.

Comment: I used a Minicircuits LZY-22+ amplifier in combination with a spiral coil that had around 10 turns and an inner diameter of 3-4 mm.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want a magnetic field which has frequency 500 MHz and you want it on a square which has side length 5 millimeters. I guess the field must be perpedicular with your square. Obviously it would be optimal if the square was only a marked area on a PCB, free of other parts than the needed coil etched to the PCB. That's because you obviously are going to insert a piece of a material on the square to get the magnetic field treatment. You already said the field must about 1 millitesla. I assume 1 mT is the wanted r.m.s. magnetic flux density, so 1.4 mT is the wanted peak value.

There's a couple of things which should be noticed:

1. The induction. Where magnetic field changes there's also an electric field. It's there, no matter we often sweep it out of our minds and imagine the induced voltage is only inside the coil metal. To stay in truth I must add that in resonators and mismatched transmission lines we may find limited areas where the electric field is cancelled, but the magnetic field has a maximum. In math these can be explained as the resultant field of waves which propagate to opposite directions.
2. You must have also some depth where the magnetic field exists. Otherwise you cannot insert anything to get the magnetic treatment.

The electric field caused by induction generates eddy currents. That happens as well in conductive materials as in insulators, where molecules start to vibrate along the changing electric field i.e. there's AC current. The caused losses can be substantial or they can be neglible depending on frequency and materials.

The volume of the wanted magnetic field area is important because that affects how much magnetic energy is needed. Let's assume the wanted volume is 5 mm high, so the field is needed in volume =125 cubic millimeters. That's 125 nanocubicmeters.

In practice it is difficult to limit the field just to that space. In low enough frequencies one could have an airgap in high permeability core, but I cannot name any low loss high permeability (hundreds) materials for 500 MHz. Even, if such core existed, one couldn't create low enough inductance with it, I guess. The needed voltage would be impractically high. The volume 125 nanocubicmeters can still be used as a limit in calculations of how much magnetic energy we at least need. We use the next rule taken from Wikipedia:

---

[image]

---

Assumed peak B = 1,4 milliteslas and the assumed volume gives peak energy =70 nanojoules. It does not look big, but you wanted the energy to grow from zero to that value in a time period 0,5 ns - that's a quarter of one 500MHz sinusoidal pulse. The average power during the growth is 140 watts.

That 140 watts can all be forth-back fluctuation in a resonant circuit if there's no losses. By connecting a parallel LC resonant circuit to the output of an amp one takes from the amp continuously only what's dissipated in losses. In theory the amp and the resonant circuit can also be a part of an oscillator. A proper control circuit is needed to keep the wanted field strength and frequency.

I'm afraid the resonant circuit cannot in practice be designed by a hobbyist otherwise than by trial and error. Very rare of us have available a high end CAD system for rf circuits +  have the needed knowledge to use it.

My best guess (which we soon try to analyze):

Make a Helmholtz pair of single turn coils to have some field uniformity.

Free online Helmholtz coil calculator https://notblackmagic.com/bitsnpieces/helmholtz-coil/ says that current value 3.1 A is enough to create  1 mT flux density if the coil is square with 5 mm sides and the single turn loops are 5.5 mm apart each other. The calculator has also loss calculation part, but it's useless here, it's for DC only. AC losses are substantially higher due the skin effect, dielectric losses and also some radiation.

The inductance of the Helmholtz coil is difficult to predict. It's not the same as for DC, because there's some distributed capacitance, too. In addition the magnetic coupling between the loops is only partial. Thus inductor calculators gives too high inductance. Tight 5x5 millimeters 2 turn coil would have maybe 20 nanohenries, but this can be as low as 10 nH (a guess).

Assumed 10 nH inductance needs about 10pF parallel capacitance to make a 500 MHz resonator. I guess at least a half of it is as distributed in wires and in the coils. The actual needed capacitor can be found only by making measurements with proper radio laboratory tools. The same is needed to estimate the needed actual power to compensate the losses.

The reactance of the 10 nH coil(pair) at 500 MHz is 31 ohms. To get the wanted 3.1 A r.m.s. current through it you need r.m.s voltage 96 volts. That's 136 volts peak.

The needed voltage is no potential cause for arcing problems if you use air insulation. The needed airgap is less than a millimeter. But nothing elementary can output 136 volts at 500MHz. A workaround might be to use 500 MHz series LC resonator with current limited output. Inductor needs still that 3.1 A current and 136 V peak voltage, but the capacitor cancels the voltage. I skip this approach.

The losses in the coil will be substantial even if we take  only the skin effect and the copper resistance into the account. The skin depth at 500 MHz is only 2.9 micrometers. An one millimeter wide and 2x4x5 mm long thin copper strip will have resistance about 116 ohms. To get 3.1 amperes through it needs 360 volts. The resistive power dissipation would be 1.1 kW. That would melt your coils in seconds if your 500MHz amp could provide it.

**Conclusion:** I cannot give a practical circuit idea how to produce the wanted flux density. Think this only an already walked blind alley.